# Maximization on the sum of the maximum of piecewise, continuous, and concavely increasing functions.

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, piecewise-continuity

I want to solve the following problem:

Given a number $M$ and functions $g_i^k, \forall i,k$, for a design variable $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^K$,

\begin{array}{cl}
\text{maximize} & \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{K} \max \left\{ f_1^k (x_k), f_2^k (x_k), \ldots, f_N^k (x_k) \right\}\\
\text{subject to} & x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_N \le M,\\
& x_i\ge0, \quad i=1, 2, \ldots,N,
\end{array}

where

\begin{equation}
f_i^k(x_k) = \begin{cases}
g_1^k(x_k), & \text{if} ~~ q_i < 0,\\
g_2^k(x_k), & \text{if} ~~ h_i(x_k) > 0,\\
g_3^k(x_k), & \text{if} ~~ q_i \ge 0 ~~ \text{and} ~~ h_i(x_k) \le 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

- The functions, $g_1^k, g_2^k, g_3^k$, are concavely increasing with respect to $x_k$ for all $k=1, 2, \ldots,K$.
- $q_i$ is given, which is a deterministic value with respect to $i$.
- $h_i$ is given, which is a function of $x_k$.
- $f_i^k$ is concavely increasing with respect to $x_k$, and continuous although it is defined as a piecewise function.

---

I guess that the problem is solvable by the traditional convex programming softwares, e.g., CVX, since $f_i^k$ is a continuous increasing concave function.

However, I am struggling with two things: One is that in the definition of function $f_i^k$, the conditional statements are dependent on $x_k$ (e.g., $h_i(x_k)>0$), and the other is that there is maximization in maximization.

Could someone please provide me ways or directions to solve the above problem?
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: It s not a convex problem. It would have been if you maximized the *smallest* of $M$ concave functions. or *minimized* the largest of $M$ *convex functions*.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Ah-ha. You mean that Problem of `max { min { concave functions } }` is convex, but Problem of `max { max { concave function } }` is not convex. Thank you for giving me a valuable comment. May I ask one more thing: can I solve the inner maximization problem, i.e., $\max_i \{ f_i^k(x_k)\}$?

Comment: You don't solve the inner problem in formulations like this, you reformulate the model. For instance, if the problem was $\max \min_i f_i$ you would have introduced a new variable $t$ and maximized this variable subject to the constraints $f_i \geq t$. However, as your model does not lend it self to a hypograph form, you have to use alternative representations, such as a MILP model,